# Only select one row at a time using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using `mouseover()`, `mouseout()` and `click()` to highlight rows on mouseover and add a highlight class on click:

```
    //Mouseover any row by adding class=mouseRow
    $(".mouseRow tr").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-active");
    });
    $(".mouseRow tr").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active");
    });
    $('.mouseRow tr').click(function(event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('selectRow'); 
    });
```

The above code will allow a user to 'highlight' (i.e add class `selectRow`) to as many rows as they want. What is the best way, using jQuery, to limit the number of rows they can select to just one (so that if they click one row, then click another it will remove the '`selectRow`' class from the previously selected row)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could remove the `selectRow` class from all of the `tr` elements except the clicked one whenever you click on one, and then toggle it on the clicked one:

```
$('.mouseRow tr').click(function(event) {
    $('.mouseRow tr').not(this).removeClass('selectRow');
    $(this).toggleClass('selectRow'); 
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kRD4S/).

Comment: huh. Looks good but when I try it I get this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: That must be a problem somewhere else in your code! You can see in the fiddle that this should work. With that error, the chances are you've forgotten to close something properly (maybe a `$(document).ready` function?)

Comment: found my missing } (accidentally pasted over it) and thanks for the hover() example

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this script at end of your html,meant after </body> tag

<script>
 $("tr").hover(function() 
 {
   $(this).addClass("hover"); 
 }, function()
    {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    });
$('tr').click(function(event) {
        $('tr').not(this).removeClass('click');
        $(this).toggleClass('click'); 
    });
</script>


This is css that highlight your row:

    .click{
background:#FF9900;
color: white
}

.hover{
background:blue;
color: white
}

here is the link of working example
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jafL2/1/)

```
Hope this will help
```

Answer (score 1):

While I first tried the toggleClass/removeClass-way with a '.clicked'-Class in CSS, it turned out to lag a bit. So, I did this instead which works better/faster:

```
$(document).on('click', '.DTA', function (event) {        
    $('.DTA').not(this).css('backgroundColor', "#FFF");
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', "#FAA");        
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MonteCrypto/mxdqe97u/27/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mouseRow tr').click(function(event) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selectRow')){
           $('.selectRow').removeClass('selectRow');
           $(this).addClass('selectRow'); 
        } else {
           $('.selectRow').removeClass('selectRow');
        }
});
```

Should do the trick. Note this still allows your toggle, if you don't want that just remove the `if(){` and `} else { ... }` parts leaving:

```
           $('.selectRow').removeClass('selectRow');
           $(this).addClass('selectRow');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('.mouseRow tr').click(function(event) {
    $('.mouseRow tr').each(function(index) {
        $(this).removeClass('selectRow');
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('selectRow'); 
});
```

You could also use the `.find()` method and wrap logic to check if any elements have this class first before removing all.

Comment: You haven't closed the `each` function, and this won't remove the class if you click on the same `tr` element twice in a row. Also, there's no need for the `each` because `removeClass` will apply to all elements in the matched set anyway.

Comment: yes good catch, i'll make the edit.  yeah no definitely, less code is better and more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery-ui .selectable function with tbody id='selectable':

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        filter: "tr", //only allows table rows to be selected
        tolerance: "fit", //makes it difficult to select rows by dragging
        selected : function(event, ui) {
            var rowid = "#"+ui.selected.id; //gets the selected row id
            //unselects previously selected row(s)
            $('tr').not(rowid).removeClass('ui-selected');
        }
    });
});
```

Each of my table rows, which were created dynamically have an id of 'task'+i